# Code reloading with leiningens checkouts feature

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using a luminus web project and added a library that I am developing in parallel to it via the checkouts feature of leiningen.
Now, what I want is that the reloading of source files works too for the project that I refer to via the checkouts folder. 
Is there way to do that? I have not succeeded so far changing the :reload-paths or wrap-reload options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end it was pretty easy, however, finding that out, was not.

In core.clj there is this code:

```
(http-kit/run-server
    (if (dev? args) (reload/wrap-reload app) app)
```

Simply change it to this one:

```
(http-kit/run-server
    (if (dev? args) (reload/wrap-reload app 
        {:dirs ["src" "checkouts/subproject/src"]}) app)
```

You can add as many folders you want, all will get watched for source changes.

Comment: Does this only apply to .clj or .cljs or ANY file?

Comment: This is a late answer, but, no, clojurescript reloading is handled by something different like cljsbuild for instance.